# Solidity: VM Exception while processing transaction: invalid opcode - What happens?

Tags: solidity, truffle, truffle-test, revert-opcode, invalid-opcode

If `VM Exception while processing transaction: invalid opcode` is thrown, does it have the same effect than revert?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Roughly. The important difference is that an invalid opcode consumes all the remaining gas, while `revert` does not. (The remaining gas is returned.)